# Substitute "which" instead of "where" in subordinate clause?

Tags: relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses

The glossary of the [C99 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) contains this entry:

> 3.17.3 **unspecified value**:
>   valid value of the relevant type **where** this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

I noticed that a *valid value of the relevant type* is not a place but it's used with *where*. Is it possible to use **which** instead of **where**?

And would the sentence work if **where** is changed to **which**?

> 3.17.3 **unspecified value**:
>   valid value of the relevant type **which** this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot directly substitute *which* instead of *where*.  The two words serve different grammatical roles.

*Where* is a subordinating conjunction.  It introduces a subordinate clause, and the clause needs a subject, which, in this case, is "this International Standard".

*Which* is a relative pronoun.  It introduces a relative clause, and stands in for a noun phrase (such as the subject) in that clause. In your example, the clause doesn't have any noun-phrase gap, so *which* doesn't fit.

If you wanted to use *which*, you could restate the definition either like so:

> 3.17.3 **unspecified value:**
> valid value of the relevant type, which could be any value, because this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

or like so:

> 3.17.3 **unspecified value:**
> valid value of the relevant type **on which** this International Standard imposes no requirements on the value chosen

Both alternatives are less readable.  I prefer the original wording.

Comment: Nice explanation - but (niggle) *which* can have any kind of noun phrase type function within the clause, it doesn't have to be subject - it could be the object for example, or part of a preposition phrase.

Comment: @Araucaria You've given me another idea, which I have just added.

Comment: Yes, but in your explanation of *which* it still says that *which* functions as the subject of the relative clause ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria On its own, _which_ would be interpreted as a subject. _On which_ would make it an object of a preposition.

Comment: If you mean in this particular sentence, in that reconstruction that's given, then yes. It sounds in your grammatical explanatory bit as though *which* in general functions as the subject of a clause ... Did you want that to be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you provided the link. I went and looked at it to get context.

So, to keep it simple: **where** is effectively conditional, while **which** would be a solid "this is how it is" type statement.

As it stands, it is saying "If the standard does not specify what this value is, then the value is an unspecified value."

If you changed it to which, then you are saying "The standard doesn't specify this."

Additionally, which makes it seem less clear as to whether you are talking about the value or the type.

The other answers are better at putting things into specific grammatical terms, so I focused more on the implications of the change.